# How to do manual code vectorization with better performance that automatic vectorization for edge detection

Tags: c++, optimization, avx512

I have been following [this](https://www.coursera.org/learn/parallelism-ia/lecture/j4Fki/2-8-stencil) coursera course and at some point the code below is given and the instructor claims that vectorization is done by including `#pragma omp simd` between the inner and outer `for` loops since guided vectorization is hard. How can I vectorize the code used in the course on my own, and is there a way to achieve better performance than if I simply add `#pragma omp simd` and move on?

```
template<typename P>
void ApplyStencil(ImageClass<P> & img_in, ImageClass<P> & img_out) {

  const int width  = img_in.width;
  const int height = img_in.height;

  P * in  = img_in.pixel;
  P * out = img_out.pixel;

  for (int i = 1; i < height-1; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < width-1; j++) {
      P val = -in[(i-1)*width + j-1] -   in[(i-1)*width + j] - in[(i-1)*width + j+1] 
    -in[(i  )*width + j-1] + 8*in[(i  )*width + j] - in[(i  )*width + j+1] 
    -in[(i+1)*width + j-1] -   in[(i+1)*width + j] - in[(i+1)*width + j+1];

      val = (val < 0   ? 0   : val);
      val = (val > 255 ? 255 : val);

      out[i*width + j] = val;
    }

}

template void ApplyStencil<float>(ImageClass<float> & img_in, ImageClass<float> & img_out);
```

I am compiling using **gcc** with the `-march=native -fopenmp` flags for **AVX512** support on a skylake processor.

```
❯ gcc -march=native -Q --help=target|grep march
  -march=                           skylake

❯ gcc -march=knl -dM -E - < /dev/null | egrep "SSE|AVX" | sort
#define __AVX__ 1
#define __AVX2__ 1
#define __AVX512CD__ 1
#define __AVX512ER__ 1
#define __AVX512F__ 1
#define __AVX512PF__ 1
#define __SSE__ 1
#define __SSE2__ 1
#define __SSE2_MATH__ 1
#define __SSE3__ 1
#define __SSE4_1__ 1
#define __SSE4_2__ 1
#define __SSE_MATH__ 1
#define __SSSE3__ 1
```

Comment: There'd be even more room for optimization for an integer type, I think.  Compilers tend to be bad at widening integers and then narrowing them again.  But the function would be buggy for `uint8_t` I think; you'd actually want `auto P = ...` because `+` and `-` on narrow integer `P` would promote to `int val` before clamping.

Comment: But even with `float`, yes there's probably something you can do with shuffling to line up the right data from each of the 3 rows involved so you can do a mix of loads and shuffles.  IDK if there's much scope for reusing partial sums.

Comment: Anyway, your question title is very generic, like you think there's some general answer.  But the answer to your question is going to be specific to vectorizing *this* stencil problem.  That's basically why it's so much work to do it manually instead of leaving it to the compiler: you have to know exactly what the CPU can / can't do efficiently, and do that yourself manually using intrinsics like `_mm512_loadu_ps(&n[(i-1)*width + j-1])`.  As well as spotting patterns in data access.

Comment: The final clamping might be doable by getting the sign bits into a mask register, then doing a zero-masked `vminps` (aka [`_mm512_maskz_min_ps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=MMX,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512&text=minps&expand=3768)).   That should have less latency than separate `minps` and `maxps`.  `_mm512_range_ps` (new in AVX512) is interesting but I think not what we need here; it can't clamp to an upper and lower bound in one instruction AFAIK.

Comment: @PeterCordes no no I only meant it for this specific problem, I got curious when the instructor said to leave it to the compiler so I am investigating how I can do it on my own.

Comment: The obvious first step would be to look at the compiler's asm output and see how it auto-vectorized.  e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ with gcc or clang `-O3 -march=skylake-avx512 -fopenmp`.  And maybe with `-ffast-math`.  If they did anything obviously terrible, you can usually avoid that with intrinsics.

Comment: `-march=native` on what actual hardware?  An IceLake laptop (`-march=skylake-client`)?  Xeon Phi (`-march=knl`)?  Or a Xeon Scalable Skylake-SP or Cascade Lake (`skylake-avx512`)?  The difference might affect which choice is best for shuffling vs. more unaligned 64-byte loads.

Comment: @PeterCordes updating the question with more relevant info.

Comment: According to your last update, you have `-march=skylake` (client), so you don't have AVX512 at all, just a normal Intel desktop chip like Skylake, Kaby Lake, or Coffee Lake.  The `-march=knl` output is irrelevant.  That's fine, you do still have AVX2 + FMA, and it's actually easier to vectorize when the max vector width isn't so wide.  (The max FLOPS throughput is half what it would be with AVX512, but it''s easier to get closer to that peak when the vector width is only half the width of a cache line, so unaligned loads sometimes don't cross a cache line boundary.)

Comment: Also, this code is missing a class definition to let it actually compile on https://godbolt.org/z/65Fjco.  I assume it's something trivial like https://godbolt.org/z/cjCjhg, perhaps using narrow `int` width and height just like your loop, not `size_t`?

Comment: how come it works if I set the flag `-march=skylake-avx512`? Yes you are correct, even though any 2d array would do I guess, you can have a look at the exact code in coursera [https://www.coursera.org/learn/parallelism-ia/supplement/2d9MO/code-download].

Comment: Are you sure you enabled `-O3 -march=skylake-avx512` to get gcc to actually *auto-vectorize*?  If you omitted `-O3` or `-O2 -fopenmp` on code with pragmas, gcc typically won't use any vector instructions, and won't use the AVX512 versions of scalar instructions either.

Comment: BTW, GCC `-O3 -march=skylake-avx512 -ffast-math` has no major brain-farts:  https://godbolt.org/z/txvwqF.   But it does one vector load per FP math op, and they're mostly unaligned.  Reusing vectors across iterations could save lots of loads.  And if you do multiple rows at once, you can even reuse the partial sums of 3 consecutive elements as both an `i-1` and an `i+1` for different `i` values..  (FP math is not strictly associative because of rounding intermediate values, but it's close enough to allow reordering.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some untested proof-of-concept implementation which uses 4 adds, 1 fmsub and 3 loads per packet (instead of 9 loads, 7 adds, 1 fmsub for a straight-forward implementation). I left out the clamping (which for `float` images looks unusual at least, and for `uint8` it does nothing, unless you change `P val = ...` to `auto val = ...`, as Peter noticed in the comments) -- but you can easily add that yourself.

The idea of this implementation is to sum up the pixels left and right (`x0_2`) as well as all 3 (`x012`) and add these from 3 consecutive rows (`a012 + b0_2 + c012`) then subtract that from the middle pixel multiplied by 8. 
At the end of each loop drop the contents of `a012` and move `bX` to `aX` and `cX` to `bX` for the next iteration.

The `applyStencil` function simply applies the first function for each column of 16 pixels (starting at `col = 1` and at the end just performs a possibly overlapping computation for the last 16 columns). If your input image has less than 18 columns you need to handle that differently (possibly by masked loads/stores).

```
#include <immintrin.h>

void applyStencilColumn(float const *in, float *out, size_t width, size_t height)
{
  if(height < 3) return; // sanity check
  float const* last_in = in + height*width;
  __m512 a012, b012, b0_2, b1;
  __m512 const eight = _mm512_set1_ps(8.0);
  {
    // initialize first rows:
    __m512 a0 = _mm512_loadu_ps(in-1);
    __m512 a1 = _mm512_loadu_ps(in+0);
    __m512 a2 = _mm512_loadu_ps(in+1);
    a012 = _mm512_add_ps(_mm512_add_ps(a0,a2),a1);
    in += width;
    __m512 b0 = _mm512_loadu_ps(in-1);
    b1 = _mm512_loadu_ps(in+0);
    __m512 b2 = _mm512_loadu_ps(in+1);
    b0_2 = _mm512_add_ps(b0,b2);
    b012 = _mm512_add_ps(b0_2,b1);
    in += width;
  }
  // skip first row for output:
  out += width;

  for(; in<last_in; in+=width, out+=width)
  {
    // precalculate sums for next row:
    __m512 c0 = _mm512_loadu_ps(in-1);
    __m512 c1 = _mm512_loadu_ps(in+0);
    __m512 c2 = _mm512_loadu_ps(in+1);
    __m512 c0_2 = _mm512_add_ps(c0,c2);
    __m512 c012 = _mm512_add_ps(c0_2, c1);

    __m512 outer = _mm512_add_ps(_mm512_add_ps(a012,b0_2), c012);
    __m512 result = _mm512_fmsub_ps(eight, b1, outer);

    _mm512_storeu_ps(out, result);
    // shift/rename registers (with some unrolling this can be avoided entirely)
    a012 = b012;
    b0_2 = c0_2; b012 = c012; b1 = c1;
  }
}

void applyStencil(float const *in, float *out, size_t width, size_t height)
{
  if(width < 18) return; // assert("special case of narrow image not implemented");

  for(size_t col = 1; col < width - 18; col += 16)
  {
    applyStencilColumn(in + col, out + col, width, height);
  }
  applyStencilColumn(in + width - 18, out + width - 18, width, height);
}
```

Possible improvements (left as an exercise):

- The `applyStencilColumn` could act on columns of 32, 48, 64, ... pixels for better cache locality (as long as you have sufficient registers). This makes implementing both functions slightly more complicated, of course.
- If you unroll 3 (or 6, 9, ...) iterations of the `for(; in<last_in; in+=width)` loop, there would be no need to actually move registers (plus the general benefit of unrolling).
- If your width is a multiple of 16, you could ensure that at least the stores are mostly aligned (except for the first and last columns).
- You could iterate just over a small number of rows at the same time (by adding another outer loop to the main function and calling `applyStencilColumn` with a fixed height. Make sure to have the right amount of overlap between row-sets. (The ideal number of rows likely depends on the size of your image).
- You could also always add 3 consecutive pixels but multiply the center pixel by 9 instead (`9*b1-outer`). Then (with some book-keeping effort) you could add `row0+(row1+row2)` and `(row1+row2)+row3` to get the `row1` and `row2` intermediate results (having 3 instead of 4 additions). Doing the same horizontally looks more complicated, though.

Of course, you should always test and benchmark any custom SIMD implementation vs what your compiler generates from the generic implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure striding down columns will work very well.  HW prefetch can handle fixed strides, but you're unavoidably touching the same cache line multiple times on successive passes because of the -1 and +1 offsets so not all your loads can be aligned.  Doing more columns in parallel might help.  Or might hurt if one column of cache lines managed to fit in L2 or L1d, e.g. the row stride wasn't a large power of 2 that made them all alias the same set.

Comment: Doing multiple *rows* in parallel while you move across columns lets you get some reuse, I think.  But cache aliasing could destroy performance if you have too many input streams for L2 or L1d associativity and an unfortunate width = row stride.  (Minimum of 8-way on Intel CPUs with AVX512, though.  Unlike Skylake-client which has only 4-way L2 associativity.)

Comment: The float clamping appears is I assume to saturate to uin8_t pixel value range for possible further calculation in the float domain.  If the next step is to convert back to uint8_t, then yes it would make much more sense to just convert to int32_t and use packing with unsigned saturation.

Comment: @PeterCordes I added another improvement regarding iterating over multiple lines. I also considered storing the `im[-1]+im[0]+im[1]` partial sum somewhere (e.g., inside the next rows of the destination array, then add 3 rows and subtract that from 9 times the center pixel). I won't investigate further into that, though.

Comment: Regarding the clamping: 'float' images "usually" are stored with a range from 0 to 1.0, so clamping with 255 would have no effect here. However, clamping to 0 actually hides black lines on white backgrounds (maybe that is intended, but unusual, and perhaps better done in the next  processing step). Nevertheless, adding the clamping should be straight-forward, if actually required.

Comment: Since we have AVX512, a single zero-masked `vminps` should do it (with mask = inverse of sign bits).  I think that's non-obvious enough to be worth showing, and one fewer FP math op than vmin / vmax as well as lower latency.

Comment: @PeterCordes Can you extract the (inverse) sign bits without producing an FP op? (Honest question, I could not find one, but I have not much experience with AVX512). The only obvious way I found was comparing with `0.0`, but that would not be faster than another `vmaxps` (nor reduce the latency), I guess. If latency was an issue, maybe comparing `8*b1` by `outer` is possible.

Comment: I was thinking [`vptestnmd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vptestnmb:vptestnmw:vptestnmd:vptestnmq) against a mask of `set1_epi32(0x80000000)` which is apparently 4c latency on port 5 (https://uops.info/) on SKX.  `VFPCLASSPS` is the same; with the right choice of immediate can give the mask we want.  `VPMOVD2M` would just extract the sign bits without inverting, which I don't think we can use.  I just remembered that Skylake-X shuts down port 1 while 512-bit uops are in flight, so avoiding a true FMA uop only helps for a 256-bit version, or on CPUs with only one FMA unit.

Comment: @chtz when will the "initialize first rows" code block run here?
I mean the computations for `a0, b0` and so on.

Comment: @dearn44 That block will always run at the beginning of `applyStencilColumn`, I used the `{ }` block mostly for structuring (and to express that `a0, a1`, etc are not required outside this block.

Comment: Then how can this be correct since we load `c` multiple times but `a` and `b` only once. Do you mind discussing this in the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214454/optimization-discussion